# Can not get instance of type derived in F# library correctly

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll, f#

I'm having a problem in my project with using types from F# in C# library.

I have an application which basically consists of the following main parts:

- core library (.NET Standard 2.1);
- WPF client.

The **core** library contains all the platform independent logic and view-models and can be used in any kind of UI clients.
The application is designed to be extensible and can plug extensions dynamically before UI is loaded. For now it's just loading *DLL's* from the specific folder via ***Assembly.LoadFrom***. The only requirement for the *dll* to be recognized as an extension is to expose special class that derives from the *Module* or *Extension* classes that are defined in **core** library. And it's working perfectly when loading assemblies written in C#.
But I got struggle with very strange behavior when trying to use extension that is written in F#.
Let's say I have an interface *IRecognitionProcessor* that is defined in my core library. Here are some of it's members:

```
public interface IRecognitionProcessor
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    bool ContainsFace(Bitmap bitmap);

    FaceDetail[] ExtractDetails(Bitmap bitmap);
    /* more members goes here */
}
```

In my new extension that provides the custom recognition based on **EmguCV** library for .NET I have a descendant to *IRecognitionProcessor* that in result will be extracted and stored in special container.
The extension is written in F#, as I've mentioned before. That's a brief example of the implementation:

```
type EmguFaceRecognition() =
interface IRecognitionProcessor with
    member this.Name : string = "EmguCV"
    member this.Description : string = "EmguCV face recognition processor"

    member this.ContainsFace (bitmap : Bitmap) : bool =
        //code goes here

    member this.ExtractDetails (bitmap : Bitmap) : FaceDetail array =
        //code goes here

    // other implementations
```

It is loaded correctly without any errors, and  all the assemblies that come along with it also loaded normally.
The problem arise when I'm fetching all the processors from my attached extensions. Here is the simplified representation of code that describes module and how it provides the processor:

```
type EmguRecognitionModule() = 
    inherit RecognitionModule()

override this.GetRecognitionProcessor() : IRecognitionProcessor =
    new EmguFaceRecognition() :> IRecognitionProcessor
// more code goes here
```

When new module is loaded - it's processor being extracted and stored in storage. Both step with instantiating module via ***Activator.CreateInstance*** and fetching it's processor via ***GetRecognitionProcessor*** method works fine.
This is the method that populates one of my view-model's collection of processors:

```
public void PopulateRecognitionProcessors(IEnumerable<IRecognitionProcessor> processors, AccessToken accessToken)
{
    if (accessToken != _parentAccessToken)
        throw new AccessViolationException("Attempt to set recognition processors from outside of the parent"); 

    _recognitionProcessors.Clear();
    _recognitionProcessors.AddRange(processors);

    SelectedProcessor = _recognitionProcessors.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Pretty simple, though it works bad when processors come from F# library. Even if there are processors, the *SelectedProcessor* property will not be assigned to the first processor at all, it's still **null**. When I put a breakpoint and tried to observe the properties of the processors stored in the collection - inspection shows none of properties.
[Here is the link to example of property inspection I've made in JetBrains Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNgze.png).
But when I'm using *Evaluate* window, I can access all the properties and methods of the object and IntelliSense works perfectly. [Link to image with example of evaluation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kvt3.png).
This whole situation makes me feel dumb. Just faced this problem first time. Previously, all my attempts to use types defined in F# libraries succeeded. But this one is an exception.
I see that using type derived from the abstract one works nice. But type that implements the interface somehow doesn't.

Comment: After some investigation found out that members added to the interface descendants are visible in Rider's property inspector.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with F# project settings and recreating the project from scratch I finally managed to resolve the problem - though the origin of the problem is still a mystery.
But still there is a problem with Rider's property inspector that shows only those members that are declared in the interface descendant directly. I'll check out JetBrains support if there are similar issues already posted.

**upd**
Seems that *DisplayMemberPath* of the **CheckBox** (specified in *XAML*) also couldn't resolve the implemented properties from the instance.

Comment: If I change the interface _IRecognitionProcessor_ to abstract class and in F# library inherit the class properly, **everything** works properly for some reason.